# How to mock Grails request object method in Spock controller test

Tags: grails, groovy, controller, spock

I'm trying to write a test for one of my controller classes. In this controller, I call `request.reader.text` which can throw `MalformedInputException` if the body contains non-utf-8 characters.

This is the case I'm trying to test and mock in my Spock test. The easiest would be if I could mock the `getReader()` method, but that turns out to be difficult.

Things I've tried:

Should work according to this post (but does not): [How to mock HttpServletRequest in Spock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10751728/how-to-mock-httpservletrequest-in-spock)

```java
GrailsMockHttpServletRequest request = new GrailsMockHttpServletRequest()
request.getReader() >> {
    throw new MalformedInputException(1)
}
```

Also tried this, as per @LeonardBrünings comment (but it seems to have no effect):

```
GroovySpy(GrailsMockHttpServletRequest, global: true) {
    getReader() >> {
        throw new MalformedInputException(1)
    }
}
```

**Reproduceable repo (run `ApplicationControllerSpec`):** https://github.com/Zorobay/test-app

Comment: Please edit your question, providing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not just a mini test snippet. A reüproducible test case dramatically improves your chance of getting helpful answers quickly.

Comment: @kriegaex there we go :)

Comment: I can reproduce the situation now, but I never used Grails or its special testing support before. I see that the request is some special kind of mock already. Maybe that mock can be configured in some way, but as you also noticed, there is no direct way of setting the reader, which is meant to be read-only. I think I am out of my depth here, and I do not want to start thinking about Groovy meta class tricks. Traits are also in the mix in Grails testing, which does not make things easier. Maybe another Grails test type is better suited, I have no idea. Someone else can help you better, sorry.

Comment: You could use a global `GroovySpy` as everything in grails is using Groovy.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings I'm not sure how I would make that work. I tried this, but it seems to have no effect (code added to question description).

Comment: There are a number of problems with the way the code is written.  One is at https://github.com/Zorobay/test-app/blob/d45b8ba1f233dee46d0df1e5c15638a893340ff9/grails-app/controllers/test/app/ApplicationController.groovy#L19-L26 which will cause `render(...)` to be invoked twice if a `MalformedInputException` is thrown.  `render` will be called in the `catch` black with a `HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST` and then immediately will be called again with `HttpStatus.OK`.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings "You could use a global GroovySpy as everything in grails is using Groovy." - That isn't really correct.  Much of Grails is written in Java. `GroovySpy` will not affect calls which are initiated from Java code.  That isn't one of the problems with the code in question here though, but just FYI.

Comment: @JeffScottBrown hi, yes that is true. I only wrote this test code quickly to illustrate my problem with Spock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution after some more frantic googling. Although, this is not as clean as I would have wished, it works!

The only way I've found it possible to manipulate the `request` and `response` objects in a controller is by calling `RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes()` with a new `GrailsWebRequest`. The downside to this is that the response object also has to be overwritten. This is not a big problem however, as it is manipulated "in-place" when calling `render()`, so we can just check the "would be" response status on our newly created object. My Spock test now looks like this:

```
def "validerHtml: håndterer MalformedInputException"() {
    given:
        String charset = "UTF-16"
        GrailsMockHttpServletRequest mockRequest = Spy(GrailsMockHttpServletRequest)
        mockRequest.getReader() >> {
            throw new MalformedInputException(1)
        }
        mockRequest.setContentType("text/html;charset=${charset}")

        GrailsMockHttpServletResponse mockResponse = new GrailsMockHttpServletResponse()
        GrailsWebRequest webRequest = new GrailsWebRequest(mockRequest, mockResponse, mockRequest.getServletContext())
        mockRequest.setAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.WEB_REQUEST, webRequest)
        RequestContextHolder.setRequestAttributes(webRequest)  // Here we overwrite the web request
    when:
        controller.validateHtml()
    then:
        0 * controller.myService.validateMessage(*_)
        // Have to check would-be response on our mocked response
        mockResponse.status == HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value()
        mockResponse.text.startsWith("Could not read request body using charset: ${charset}")
}
```

Comment: Don't forget that you need this in your build.groovy file: `compile "org.grails:grails-test"`